# Show current page on the menu Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'd like to change the background color of the current page the user is on. I've tried some code but they don't work.
My js code is in a different file and it's loading the menu to some of the pages.

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu-nav").load("menu.html");
    $("#footer").load("footer.html");
})


/* The menu code is in another file */
<div class="menu-nav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="homeLink" href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="pessoal" class="a-borda" href="pessoal.html">pessoal</a></li>
        <li><a id="galeria" href="galeria.html">galeria</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The code I've tried, but the class is not added

```
var section = window.location.pathname;

    if (section == "/index.html"){$("#homeLink").attr("class", "active");}

CSS:
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

also tried with .addClass( className ), but doesn't add the class.
I don't know if the fact I'm bringing the files with Jquery it's interfering in the process or if I'm using the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class dynamically depending on the page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let section = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
  $(`a[href='${section}']`).addClass("active");
})
```

Comment: That works when I try on the browser console but doesn't work when I add to the actual file. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Do you have a file with this script added to all html pages?

Comment: That's right, I forgot one of them. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `var section = window.location.pathname; ... if (section == "/index.html"){$("#homeLink").attr("class", "active");}` into a `$(function(){`. This lets the script wait until the DOM finishes loading.

```js
$(function(){
  var section = window.location.pathname;
  //Changed the section to /js as the script is run from https://stacksnippets.net/js 
  if (section == "/js") {
    $("#homeLink").addClass("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-nav">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a id="homeLink" href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a id="pessoal" class="a-borda" href="pessoal.html">pessoal</a></li>
        <li><a id="galeria" href="galeria.html">galeria</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: _"This lets the script wait until the DOM finishes loading."_ - but the menu won't be available then, because it itself only gets loaded, when the DOM has finished loading, with `$("#menu-nav").load("menu.html")`. This should be done inside a callback of this `load` call.